# Is it possible to place TODO keywords at end of heading

Tags: org-mode, todo

I want to have an org file like this example :

```
#+OPTIONS: 
#+TYP_DODO: KO | OK
#+TODO: KO | OK


* Automated tests results [62%] / [5/8]
:PROPERTIES:
:COOKIE_DATA: recursive
:END:
** results group 1 [50%]
*** test 1 : OK
*** test 2 : KO
*** test 3 : OK
*** test 4 : KO
** results group 2 [75%]
*** test 1 : KO
*** test 2 : OK
*** test 3 : OK
*** test 4 : OK
```

To achieve this I need to have the TODO keyword at the end of the heading line instead of at the beginning.
Is it possible? If so how?

Comment: Not possible, sorry. You can use tags instead as a workaround `:tag:`.

Comment: Ok, but how do you update the counters ? Could you be kind enough to provide me an example ?

Comment: That is a different question.  You'll need to launch a new question for that, but, please do a Google search beforehand just in case there are already answers or tutorials that explain how to do it.

Comment: Do you need the specific format because you are you generating a report for another automated tool?